# Permission problem when installing package from tlmgr

Tags: packages, texlive

I migrated from `MiKTeX` on windows to `TeXLive` in ubuntu. At first I installed `texlive-full` from ubuntu repositories but I realized that I wanted to install more packages which isn't very convenient when there is no `tlmgr`.

So I decided to remove`TeXLive` and reinstall it from TUG. The installation had no problems. Then I added the following lines to `bashrc`

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/i386-linux
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2014/tlpkg/
```

and then I run a simple document and it seemed to be working. I tried to install a package(i.e. `units`) through `tlmgr` but I don't have permission to write to a specific directory. What I did was to use `sudo` privilleges but again no luck. My effort is the following

```
thanos@thanos-laptop:~$ tlmgr install units
You don't have permission to change the installation in any way,
specifically, the directory /usr/local/texlive/2014/tlpkg/ is not writable.
Please run this program as administrator, or contact your local admin.
thanos@thanos-laptop:~$ sudo tlmgr install units
[sudo] password for thanos: 
sudo: tlmgr: command not found
```

I also tried through the relevant tlmgr's gui but I get the same message as above.

What can I do to install packages through `tlmgr`?

Comment: If you do `sudo su` and then `tlmgr .... ` should work. But be careful with commands as root.

Comment: You don't need to add `/usr/local/texlive/2014/tlpkg/` to `PATH`. You should add `/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/i386-linux` at the *beginning* of `PATH` rather than the end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I did was to let `sudo` know about the modification of the `$PATH` variable. This was done typing the following command on terminal

```
sudo env PATH="$PATH" tlmgr
```

In this way, I somehow enabled `sudo` in `tlmgr`. After that packages can be installed using

```
sudo tlmgr install package
```

Answer (score 7):

In case anyone else tried previous suggestions and they didn't work, this worked for me:

```
sudo /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr ...
```

Comment: Using the `which` construction in back quotes can be of help too. For example:
```sudo \`which tlmgr\` gui``` (it is rendered not the proper way, but one can get the idea, I hope)

Answer (score 4):

Thanos' answer basically works, but the description of multiple commands is misleading.

*All* root actions will need to be explicitly paired with the `env` modification.
By design, the environmental variables for the root user are reset every time it is invoked.  If you subsequently try to execute a regular `sudo` command, the `PATH` variable will have already been reset.  This holds even in a `sudo su` environment.  So for instance, if you wanted to use the `--dry-run` option to preview installing a package named `package`, the following would **NOT** work:

```
 sudo env PATH="$PATH" tlmgr install package --dry-run

 sudo tlmgr install package
```

Instead, you have to fix the `PATH` variable every time, like this:

```
 sudo env PATH="$PATH" tlmgr install package --dry-run

 sudo env PATH="$PATH" tlmgr install package
```

The underlying problem is that a standard TeX Live installation places the binaries in a non-standard directory, so the set of `PATH` locations that root is designed to recognize does not include anything that came with TeX Live.  By design, you are not supposed to be able to permanently modify root's `PATH` variable, so any task that needs privilege elevation becomes tricky.

[Approaches to fixing this issue more permanently are described on the Ubuntu forums.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66498/setting-tex-live-path-for-root)  Doing so is more involved, and I haven't tried it myself.