# Texlive 2021 and tlmgr: an unsolved issue

Tags: texlive, paths, tlmgr, texlive-2021

I have installed Texlive 2021 on UBUNTU 21.04 from tug.org. I have had to install it as root user since, while trying to install it as simple user he didn't let the installer write in some directories. Following, the guide I have updated the paths in the `$HOME/.profile` file adding the following expressions:

```
if [ -d "/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux" ] ; then
PATH="$HOME/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH" 
fi 
if [ -d "/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/man" ] ; then
MANPATH="/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH" 
fi 
if [ -d "/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/info" ] ; then 
INFOPATH="/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH" 
fi
```

This way Latex works fine. As for tlmgr, in root mode, I can open and operate the GUI. I tried, still in root mode (https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/manpath.1.htmlin user mode ir says I have to run it in root mode)

```
tlmgr update --self (and > tlmgr update --self)
```

It gave me the following message:

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!) 
(see /usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md) 
TLPDB: not a directory, not loading: /root/texmf tlmgr: 
user mode not initialized, please read the documentation!
```

I tried to employ `--usermode` and `--usertree` with no success. Finally I wrote

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH
MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH 
INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH
```

This way it works. Any alternative, that saves me copying and pasting those instruction? When writing

```
echo $PATH, >echo $MANPATH, echo $INFOPATH
```

the terminal lists the corrects directories. What's missing? I think I should set a PATH, but where? Thanks in advance

**UPDATE! (partially solved but not quite)**

I copied the `$PATH`, `$MANPATH`, `$INFOPATH` on the `.bashrc` file. Now `tlmgr update -all` works fine. Unfortunately, `tlmgr update --self` responds this way.

```
tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2020) is older than remote repository (2021).
Cross release updates are only supported with update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update 
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
```

I have tried to follow the suggestions on the upgrade page of tug.org/texlive without success.

Comment: if you installed as root (or better using sudo) then you need to update using the same account so `sudo tlmgr update --all`   you are clearly running a tlmgr from a local texlive 2020 not teh texlive 2021 in your final note

Comment: it looks like you are using the debian tlmgr not the texlive 2021 one, try  `sudo /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update --all`

Comment: Thanks! It works! Do you know hoe to update the path permanently?

Comment: here for example https://askubuntu.com/questions/57915/environment-variables-when-run-with-sudo/713137#713137

Comment: Thanks I'll check, but I was too much of an optimist. I didn't wait the end of the process. While the command produced some sort of an updating, the message ended again in (running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
(see /usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md)

tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2020) is older than remote repository (2021).
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details. I'm thinking going back to Ubuntu 20.04 and Texlive 2019.

Comment: if you get the user mode message you are running the debian texlive not the one installed in tl2021 make sure your path is set first using the full path in the call doesn't ensure all scripts use the tl2021 versions.

Answer (score 1):

After install `texlive 2021` from [Installing TeX Live over the Internet](https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html):

Add to your `.profile`:

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH
MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH
INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH
```

and to `.bash_aliases`:

```
alias psudo='sudo env PATH="$PATH"'
```

Update `texlive` with:

```
psudo tlmgr update --all
```

(I have done this for years, in Ubuntu and Debian)

Comment: This is the solution, but some useful links on it are:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187073/permission-problem-when-installing-package-from-tlmgr
https://askubuntu.com/questions/66498/setting-tex-live-path-for-root